# Service Fabric https endpoint with kestrel and reverse proxy

Tags: https, reverse-proxy, azure-service-fabric, kestrel

I've been trying to setup Https on a stateless API endpoint following the instructions on the microsoft documentations and diverse post/blogs I could find. It works fine locally, but I'm struggling to make it work after deploying it on my dev server getting

```
Browser : HTTP ERROR 504
Vm event viewer : HandlerAsyncOperation EndProcessReverseProxyRequest failed with FABRIC_E_TIMEOUT
SF event table : Error while processing request: request url = https://mydomain:19081/appname/servicename/api/healthcheck/ping, verb = GET, remote (client) address = xxx, request processing start time = 2018-03-13T14:50:17.1396031Z, forward url = https://0.0.0.0:44338/api/healthcheck/ping, number of successful resolve attempts = 48, error = 2147949567, message = , phase = ResolveServicePartition
```

in code I have in the instancelistener

```
    .UseKestrel(options =>
    {
       options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 44338, listenOptions =>
       {
           listenOptions.UseHttps(GetCertificate());
       });
    })
```

servicemanifest

```
<Endpoint Protocol="https" Name="SslServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="44338" />
```

startup

```
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.SslPort = 44338;
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        });
```

+

```
            var options = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps(StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently, 44338);
        app.UseRewriter(options);
```

here is what I got in azure (deployed through ARM template)

```
Health probes
NAME                    PROTOCOL    PORT    USED BY
AppPortProbe            TCP         44338   AppPortLBRule
FabricGatewayProbe      TCP         19000   LBRule
FabricHttpGatewayProbe  TCP         19080   LBHttpRule
SFReverseProxyProbe     TCP         19081   LBSFReverseProxyRule

Load balancing rules
NAME                    LOAD BALANCING RULE                 BACKEND POOL                    HEALTH PROBE
AppPortLBRule           AppPortLBRule (TCP/44338)           LoadBalancerBEAddressPool       AppPortProbe
LBHttpRule              LBHttpRule (TCP/19080)              LoadBalancerBEAddressPool       FabricHttpGatewayProbe
LBRule                  LBRule (TCP/19000)                  LoadBalancerBEAddressPool       FabricGatewayProbe
LBSFReverseProxyRule    LBSFReverseProxyRule (TCP/19081)    LoadBalancerBEAddressPool       SFReverseProxyProbe
```

I have a Cluster certificate, ReverseProxy Certificate, and auth to the api through azure ad and in ARM

```
                "fabricSettings": [
                {
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "ClusterProtectionLevel",
                            "value": "[parameters('clusterProtectionLevel')]"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Security"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ApplicationGateway/Http",
                    "parameters": [
                      {
                        "name": "ApplicationCertificateValidationPolicy",
                        "value": "None"
                      }
                    ]
                }
            ],
```

Not sure what else could be relevant, if you have any ideas/suggestions, those are really welcome

Edit : code for GetCertificate()

```
    private X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
    {
        var certificateBundle = Task.Run(async () => await GetKeyVaultClient()
            .GetCertificateAsync(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KeyVaultCertifIdentifier")));
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2();
        certificate.Import(certificateBundle.Result.Cer);
        return certificate;
    }

    private KeyVaultClient GetKeyVaultClient() => new KeyVaultClient(async (authority, resource, scope) =>
    {
        var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TokenCache.DefaultShared);
        var clientCred = new ClientCredential(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KeyVaultClientId"),
            Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KeyVaultSecret"));
        var authResult = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred);
        return authResult.AccessToken;
    });
```

Comment: Have you configured the endpoint binding in AplicationManifest? Other from that, if you login to your dev machine and examine the ports, do you see 44338 open? Another thing I'd recommend is to enable ConsoleRedirection logging in your ServiceManifest to see if anything meaningful will pop up there. And, of course, you could verify SF logs in Event Viewer.

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply, ports are open yes. according to microsoft doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-service-manifest-resources#example-specifying-an-https-endpoint-for-your-service) that would be the EndpointCertificate and EndpointBindingPolicy?  I'm not really sure to which certificate it refers, is it the clusters or the reverseproxy? One last thing I was concerned about is the ACLs on the server, I read it could be wrong, looking into how to check that and change it if necessary

Comment: Refer to this example - https://matt.kotsenas.com/posts/https-in-service-fabric-web-api. You'll find there how you should tie your service in the AppManifest with the certificate. It's not about the reverseproxy though, it's about telling SF what cert it should bind the endpoint with. Also make sure you have your cert installed on the dev machine.

Comment: As the link doesn't speak at all about reverse proxy I suppose thats the clusters certificate. All the certs used are defined in the ARM template, so it "should" be at the right place already. I'll try all that, thanks for your help.

Comment: still not working after adding to the appmanifest what was missing. I redeployed my cluster to set logs to verbose though I have this kind of messages "ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT" or "Re-resolved service url = https://0.0.0.0:44338/api/healthcheck/ping". the 0.0.0.0:44338 looks kinda odd ...

Comment: so I either messed up the probe/lb rules, had to give the RP certificate instead of the cluster certificate, or i have an ACL problem somwhere/somehow ...

Comment: have you tried to hit the endpoint locally on that machine rather than via reverse proxy? does it work?

Comment: you mean remote on the vm and ping https://localhost:44338/appname/servicename/api/healthcheck/ping ? that doesnt work ... app was working fine before trying to setup https with what i posted above though, and no deployment error shows up

Comment: PS: I'm a simple .Net dev, never had to manage all this, still learning ;)

Comment: Learning is the best thing as it opens new doors. One more question , how did you generate your cert?

Comment: with the Invoke-AddCertToKeyVault from the ServiceFabricRPHelpers helper

Comment: Here is the interesting thing. I was able to get the endpoint up and running via https with your code. Probably one difference was that I was calling  listenOptions.UseHttps passing a path to my pfx file and password rather then grabbing cert from the store. When I tried to create an instance of X509Certificate2, things got broken. So how have you implemented GetCertificate()? For what it's worth, try to upload pfx file with a private key to the vm and change the code to refer to this file. If it does a trick, probably there is an issue with the way we get an instance of X509Certificate2.

Comment: oh no this certificate is generated differently, sorry I forgot to mention, it's a combination of those 2 : https://www.humankode.com/asp-net-core/develop-locally-with-https-self-signed-certificates-and-asp-net-core

Comment: https://appswin.co.th/2018/02/26/c-retrieve-key-secret-certificate-from-azure-keyvault/

Comment: other than that, you used the exact same code/configs (including probe/lb rules) and it worked? that would narrow it down quite a bit !

Comment: Other from loading a cert from the pfx file, I've reused your code and managed to get it working but only after I added RunAsPolicy into the AppManifest to run the service under admin account.

Comment: I guess I've narrowed it down. The default account that service has been running with didn't have a privilege to read the private key. I've checked it with winhttpcertcfg tool. Once the access was granted, everything got up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Digging into your code I've realized that there is nothing wrong with it except one thing. I mean, as you use Kestrel, you don't need to set up anything extra in the AppManifest as those things are for Http.Sys implementation. You don't even need to have an endpoint in the ServiceManifest(although recommended) as all these things are about URL reservation for the service account and SSL binding configuration, neither of which is required with Kestrel.

What you do need to do is to use IPAddress.IPv6Any while you configure SSL. Aside the fact that it turns out to be the recommended way which allows you to accept both IPv4 and IPV6 connections, it also does a 'correct' endpoint registration in the SF. See, when you use IPAddress.Any, you'll get the SF setting up an endpoint like https://0.0.0.0:44338, and that's how the reverse proxy will try to reach the service which obviously wouldn't work. 0.0.0.0 doesn't correspond to any particular ip, it's just the way to say 'any IPv4 address at all'. While when you use IPAddress.IPv6Any, you'll get a correct endpoint mapped to the vm ip address that could be resolved from within the vnet. You could see that stuff by yourself in the SF Explorer if you go down to the endpoint section in the service instance blade.

Comment: the endpoint binding was a miss indeed, for the second point, I'm really not sure, point of this implementation is to go get the certificate in the keyvault instead of local store, will dig in a bit still, but I would expect something more network related with the error mentioned yesterday (ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT), so I believe I need to understand more how probes/lb rules work

Comment: SF doesn't get the cert for the keyvault when it comes to getting services up and running. The keyvault is used when VMs get set up to install certificates in the cluster. If you can't reach the endpoint locally, it has nothing to do with probes/lb rules.

Comment: did i even tried to reach it the correct way (ping 
 localhost:44338/appname/servicename/api/healthcheck/ping)? Checking the certif at runtime this way worked fine for localhost, I had assumed it would be the same while deployed on my dev cluster, alright will test this

Comment: tried to execute winhttpcertcfg with admin account on the vm, got : Error: Access was not successfully obtained for the private key.
       This can only be done by the user who installed the certificate.

Comment: Let's try the hammer approach to confirm the theory. I'll add to the answer the way you could run your service under admin account.

Comment: had that already (close enough)   <Principals>
    <Users>
      <User Name="SfAdminUser">
        <MemberOf>
          <SystemGroup Name="Administrators" />
        </MemberOf>
      </User>
    </Users>
  </Principals>
  <Policies>
    <DefaultRunAsPolicy UserRef="SfAdminUser" />
  </Policies>

Comment: So you had your service running under admin account but it didn't work anyway?

Comment: yes because the certifs I can see in the local store (cluster and reverse proxy) are installed through ARM templates, so apparently I can't access them when logging manually, and for this 3rd one well its just a certif stored in keyvault and accessed at runtime so its nowhere in the store

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the SF needs to have that https/ssl cert in the store to grab it and tie to the endpoint.

Comment: full log message : Forwarding request to service failed, retrying with re-resolve: phase = SendRequestHeaders, error = 3489661157, internal error = ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT

Comment: 0ac5edde-a99d-4016-a57a-544421baad50 Error while processing request: number of successful resolve attempts = 47, error = 2147949567, message = , phase = BeginResolve,

Comment: 0ac5edde-a99d-4016-a57a-544421baad50 Re-resolved service url = https://0.0.0.0:44338/api/healthcheck/ping

Comment: ok so if the "Forwarding request to service failed" is indeed a certificate error and not LB/probe issue, maybe instead of using this cert I can use the cluster cert, then the RP cert if clust cert doesnt work, I'll start doing this kind of tests I suppose

Comment: Yep, it's definitely worth a shot.

Comment: I'am actually not sure how to be doing that I can see the certs and their thumbprints by doing that Get-ChildItem -path cert:\LocalMachine\My but I think I would have to recreate the physical file as only th key value is copied in the store after deployment of vmss from the ARM.

Comment: but another concern is that I have no exception being thrown in the ReliableServiceEventTable.

Comment: shouldn't that mean that it doesnt even enter the app?

Comment: Not sure about ReliableServiceEventTable. Let's try it simple and run your service as a simple console app on your local machine using the same cert. Will it work? Next move it to your local SF cluster. How will it do there?

Comment: with the same cert no, I created one for localhost, which works fine and one for my custom domain, created the exact same way with CN=mycustomdomain; I'll modify my getcert method to grab the clusters certificate at runtime in the localstore instead of this certif in the keyvault

Comment: Oh, I thought that you've modified the code already to get the cluster cert. Yeah, try it this way.

Comment: Ok. Would you share all the code you have at this moment? Maybe via dropbox, google drive or whatever? Along with your cluster cert? I'll try to carve out some time during the weekend to replicate the issue.

Comment: I don't mind but it contains some info about my company I would have to clean first, and from what we saw, code is fine, meaning it's a configuration problem, therefore I would guess the problem comes from either the ARM template, some incorrect certificate, or something directly in Azure ...

Comment: Well, not sure how else I could help then :)

Comment: ahah, true, I'll prepare that then

Comment: gdrive access to the zip (once you've taken it I'll remove, let me know if you can aceess it) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1goVkWjQPbfzDHEn5wWsJern7ZYq6F-nX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I've got it. I'll let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Hey, I've got a few ideas I'm working on. If you don't mind, I'd like you to verify one thing. Install in the cloud your latest version that works with a correct cert, and try to hit next endpoint - https://localhost:44338/api/healthcheck/ping.

Comment: Another thing I'd like you to do, is to change the way you set up Kestrel. Swap IPAddress.Any with IPAddress.IPv6Any, and once new code installed, check https://mydomain:19081/appname/servicename/api/healthcheck/ping.

Comment: if I remote to one of my node and ping with cmd I got : Ping request could not find host localhost:44338/api/healthcheck/ping.  I'll try redeploy app with IPv6Any

Comment: Just in case, have you tried https:// or http? It needs to be https in all the cases.

Comment: https://mycluster.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:19081/myapp/myservice/api/healthcheck/ping WORKS !! , those 3 timeout : http://mycluster.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:19081/myapp/myservice/api/healthcheck/ping
https://mycustomdomain:19081/myapp/myservice/api/healthcheck/ping
http://mycustomdomain:19081/myapp/myservice/api/healthcheck/ping

Comment: might need a little explanation here, how come defining kestrel's listener to accept anyipv6 would help?

Comment: //     Provides an IP address that indicates that the server must listen for client
//     activity on all network interfaces. This field is read-only.
public static readonly IPAddress Any;
//     The System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(System.Net.EndPoint) method uses the System.Net.IPAddress.IPv6Any
//     field to indicate that a System.Net.Sockets.Socket must listen for client activity
//     on all network interfaces.
public static readonly IPAddress IPv6Any;  ???

Comment: Ok, I'll provide the explanation in the answer. So do you confirm that you've got it running?

Comment: yeah the complete ip is reachable, I'll have to tweak it so that the call to my domain is done through http not https though then redirect. I'll probably test the other listener options' , but I got things to work with, I can move forward, thank you so much

Comment: Awesome! Mark the answer as a correct one and we call it a day then. Thanks much for the prompt cooperation.

Comment: @KirylZ - could you provide a link explaining ServiceFabric internals regarding as to why is it that way? I mean - why IPAddress.Any gets incorrect mapping while IPv6Any get correct?

Comment: @GrayCat I've sort of figured it out in a hard way :) I mean while I was experimenting. Haven't investigated SF's internals on this matter. But, even though it's not an explanation, here is a link where SF team precisely points out that you need to use IPv6Any - [Configure Kestrel to use HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-dotnet-app-enable-https-endpoint#configure-kestrel-to-use-https).